# How to enable 'reboot' and 'shutdown' on a fresh debian install

Tags: linux, debian, root, administration

I just installed a new Debian System from the *Testing-Repository*:

```
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid   
          Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-2-amd64
    Architecture: x86-64
```

for some reason when I login as `root` I do not have certain commands like `shutdown` or `reboot` available.

**How do I fix this? Is there a packet missing?**

Comment: @roaima this is not `sid` - this is the `testing` repository in the beginning, while containing `sid` packages…

Comment: Did you try `sudo shutdown`? Which package do you expect to contain reboot and shutdown? In my Ubuntu `systemd-sysv` is installed, and `molly-guard` seems to be an alternative.

Comment: @roaima yea I know what you mean. If I recall correctly `hostnamctl` prints `sid` after a backslash since buster or so, as long as the `testing` repository contains `sid` packages. As soon as the debian testing version gets into the `freeze` status, before mooving into stable, the `sid` is not being displayed anymore. Though I do not know from where `hostnamectl` takes the info.

Comment: Nath thank you for that. Happy to remove all my comments to keep your question looking clean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These two commands are SysV-era commands; they're only "emulated" on modern systems:

`shutdown` is just a symbolic link to `systemctl`, which "knows" that when it's invoked as `shutdown` should trigger the same actions as `systemctl poweroff`. Same for `reboot`/`systemctl reboot`.

So, either you simply replace `shutdown` with `systemctl poweroff`, and `reboot` with `systemctl reboot`, or you just add aliases (`alias shutdown=systemctl poweroff`).

My recollection is that you can alternatively install the `systemd-sysv` package, which isn't that useful beyond containing exactly these symlinks.

Comment: `apt install systemd-sysv` prints: `systemd-sysv is already the newest version (249.7-1).`

Comment: @nath well, [systemd-sysv most definitely contains these files](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/amd64/systemd-sysv/filelist), so your `$PATH` must be missing crucial entries.

Comment: New behaviour https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918754#51

Comment: @MarcusMüller is clear the logical relation about `reboot`/`systemctl reboot`, but _being curious_: why is applied or exists the `shutdown`/`systemctl poweroff` relation? and _not_ something like `poweroff`/`systemctl poweroff` and `shutdown`/`systemctl shutdown`?

Comment: Basically, because someone decided it was like that? Systemctl's argument for shutting down and powering off is called `poweroff`; that was probably simply a design decision as good as any other.